# Spring 3.1.2 + Tiles 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles

I am trying configurate my Spring project with tiles but is not working. I will put my code here, if someone knows the solutions. I will appreciate:

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/login-png--25

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/project-png--6

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/spring-servlet-png

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/tiles-png

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/webxml-png

Comment: Can you share your **applicationContext** file and the **web.xml**?

Comment: Certainly, there are missed steps, can you share with us the documentation used to implement your solution? Any way, check [this] http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse/ it can be helpful